# AS3 Screen Scraping

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I am trying to find all of the text within a H1 tag in a web page.  I am using the code :

```
myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    webText = e.target.data;
    headingText = webText.match( /<H1>([^]*?)<\/H1>/ ); 
}

myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.MyWebPage.com"));
```

When it's done I get four entries in my array :
The first two are what I would expect, but the next two are
headingText[2] = 401
headingText[3] = [The entire contents of the webpage.]

What am I doing wrong?

Additionally, I am getting the H1 tags in the results.  Is there a way to tell the expression to give me everything inside the H1 tag, without the H1 tag?

Thank You,

Comment: try xml... var webText:XML = new XML(event.target.data); theTags = webText..h1 now you'll have an XMLList of all h1 tags

Comment: his problem is with RegEx and [match](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#match%28%29) method. Victorkhugo have first found result as there is no global flag - also the ignore case flag would be useful to find h1 and H1 - change your reg ex to: `/\<h1>(.*?)\<\/h1>/gis`, and as a helper wih working/testing patterns you may find very useful [RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation for match method shows:

> If pattern is a regular expression, in order to return an array with more than one matching substring, the g (global) flag must be set in the regular expression:
>
> - If the g (global) flag is not set, the return array will contain no more than one match, and the lastIndex property of the regular expression remains unchanged.
> - If the g (global) flag is set, the method starts the search at the beginning of the string (index position 0). If a matching substring is an empty string (which can occur with a regular expression such as /x*/), the method adds that empty string to the array of matches, and then continues searching at the next index position. The lastIndex property of the regular expression is set to 0 after the method completes.
>
> When the pattern parameter is a regular expression with the g (global) flag set, if no match is found the method returns an empty Array. If the pattern parameter is a String or a non-global regular expression and no match is found, the method returns null. If you pass no value (or an undefined value) as the pattern parameter, the method returns null.

problem was that you haven't specified global flag and you got at most one result, to fix it just add `g` to your regex pattern. but you can;'t be sure that loaded page will have H1 or h1 used then you should also add `i` - flag for ignore case and last flag you will need is for dotall to match new-line characters. Your revised regular expression should look like this:

```
webText.match( /\<H1>(.*?)\<\/H1>/gis );
```

@Jason Reeves proposed good solution however not all HTML pages are correct XML files (valid) meaning that `var webText:XML = new XML(event.target.data);` will throw error on any error in "XML" making this solution unusable for sources that you haven't got control.